# Niether Copy nor Move constructor called in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor

I have the following Class for test !!

```
class ArrayClass
{
private:
    int isize;
    double* p ;
public:
    ArrayClass(int num_ =1):isize(num_),p(new double[num_])
    {
        cout << "constructor with num!!" << endl ;
        for(int idx=0;idx<num_;idx++)
        {
            p[idx] = 0.0 ;
        }
    }
    ArrayClass(const ArrayClass& m) //copy constructor
    {
        cout << "copy constructor!!" << endl ;
        isize = m.getsize() ;
        p = new double[isize] ;
        std::copy(m.getaddr(), m.getaddr() + m.getsize(), p);
    }
    ArrayClass& operator=(const ArrayClass& m) //copy assignment
    {
        cout << "copy assignment!!" << endl ;
        if(this != &m)
        {
            int msize =  m.getsize() ;
            if(isize != msize )
            {
                delete []p ;
                p = 0x00 ;
                p = msize ? new double[msize] : 0x00 ;
                isize = msize ;
            }
            std::copy(m.getaddr(), m.getaddr() + msize, p);
        }
        return *this ;
    }
    ArrayClass& operator=(ArrayClass&& m)
    {
        cout << "Move assignment!!" << endl ;
        isize = m.getsize() ;
        p = m.getaddr() ;
        m.initialize() ;
        return *this ;
    }
    ArrayClass(ArrayClass&& m)
    {
        cout << "Move Constructor!!" << endl ;
        isize = m.getsize() ;
        p = m.getaddr() ;
        m.initialize() ;
    }
    ~ArrayClass()
    {
        cout << "desctrutor!!" << endl ;
        delete []p ;
    }
    void initialize(){ isize=0; p=0x00; }
    int  getsize() const { return isize; }
    double* getaddr() const { return p; }
    double& operator[](int i)
    {
        if( i >= isize)
            throw "the bound is wrong!!" ;
        return p[i] ;
    }
    const double& operator[](int i) const
    {
        if( i >= isize)
            throw "the bound is wrong!!" ;
        return p[i] ;
    }
    void Print(void)
    {
        for(int idx=0;idx<isize;idx++)
            cout << p[idx] << " " ;
        cout << endl ;
    }
} ;

ArrayClass  func()
{
    ArrayClass m(10) ;
    for(int idx=0;idx<10;idx++)
        m[idx] = idx * idx + 1 ;
    return m ;
}
```

compiled at g++ 4.4.6 in RedHat Linux with g++ --std=c++0x x.cpp -o x.exe

the follwoing is what I expected :

```
ArrayClass m2(std::move(func())) ;
m2.Print() ;
```

output :

```
constructor with num!!
Move Constructor!!
desctrutor!!
1 2 5 10 17 26 37 50 65 82
desctrutor!!
```

But the following is not what I expected :

```
ArrayClass m2(func()) ;
m2.Print() ;
```

output :

```
constructor with num!!
1 2 5 10 17 26 37 50 65 82
desctrutor!!
```

I expect there should be  "copy constructor!!"  , I am curious , no copy constructor called , also no move constructor called in this test , how come the answer of m2.Print() is right ?!

Comment: How many copy/move elision questions on daily basis?

Comment: And also you should expect move construction when passing an prvalue.

Comment: What happens if you compile with the GCC option `-fno-elide-constructors`? That should give you your answer.

Comment: After you understand what the issue is, the lesson to take home is *do not help the compiler*. Let it do its magic, don't force a move when the compiler could very well elide the whole operation!

Comment: @David , thanks , copy elision really help performance a lot to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called copy elision (although you're basically eliding a move operation here). You can construct the object in place if the semantics remain unchanged.

Comment: Technically it is still called *copy elision* even when the operation elided is a *move*. 12.8/31 *[...]This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision[...]*

Comment: http://definedbehavior.blogspot.tw/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html  this webpage really explain copy elision a lot !! excellent work !!